# Incorrect total size result from powershell

Tags: powershell, diskspace, nas

I'm facing a problem which the result of getdrive is not accurate. Clueless.

As seen in the screenshots below, 10.1.105.203 has a total space of 7.81TB, but from what powershell gives me, it is only roughly 4TB. Pretty confusing here.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not really using PowerShell. You're using the Windows Scripting Host's object model, the precursor to PowerShell, from PowerShell. Try using either:

```
C:\PS> Get-Volume

DriveLetter FileSystemLabel FileSystem DriveType HealthStatus SizeRemaining      Size
----------- --------------- ---------- --------- ------------ -------------      ----
C                           NTFS       Fixed     Healthy           94.34 GB 237.96 GB
            Recovery        NTFS       Fixed     Healthy           10.19 MB    300 MB
```

or

```
C:\PS> Get-WmiObject Win32_Volume | Format-Table DriveLetter,Capacity,FreeSpace

DriveLetter      Capacity    FreeSpace
-----------      --------    ---------
C:           255505461248 101292863488
                314568704     10682368
```

Comment: Thanks for the correction.
the drive that I try to get volume from, is a NAS, which is not listed in the win32_volume.
Can I have more clue on that?

Comment: Thanks @Keith Hill, I got it now!

Answer (score 4):

You can also use Get-Psdrive to get the size of a drive.

```
PS C:\> Get-PSDrive -PSProvider filesystem

Name           Used (GB)     Free (GB) Provider      Root
----           ---------     --------- --------      ----
C                  48.92        195.13 FileSystem    C:\
D                  30.82         69.18 FileSystem    D:\
E                    .12        121.49 FileSystem    E:\
```

You can always do a little manipulation to achieve multiple things with this, e.g,

```
PS C:\> Get-PSDrive -PSProvider filesystem | select Name, @{n= 'Used(GB)' ; e = {"{0:N2}" -f ($_.used/1GB)}}, @{n= 'Free
(GB)' ; e = {"{0:N2}" -f ($_.Free/1GB)}}, @{n= 'Total(GB)' ; e = {"{0:N2}" -f (($_.used + $_.Free)/1GB)}} | ft -auto

Name Used(GB) Free(GB) Total(GB)
---- -------- -------- ---------
C    48.92    195.13   244.04
D    30.82    69.18    100.00
E    0.12     121.49   121.62
```

Answer (score 0):

Full agree with @Keith Hill, with the PowerShell way to get the result. The strange behaviour is that for your drive `L:`, I can see that the total size is ok for the 10Tb drive, so I would not be surprise if you receive the same results from the new commands.

The next thing, I would check is if **quotas** are activated on your server.

You can also use :

```
Get-WmiObject Win32_logicaldisk -filter "driveType=4"
```